# Extract data from Google Sheets to Google Slides pages not working

Tags: google-apps-script

So I have a Google sheet, and a Google Slide, and I've used a script which extracts data from the Google sheet and adds it into a templated Google Slide.

Example of the sheet is below:
[Google Sheet Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJNop.png)

The Google slide template is:
[Google Slide Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amiN8.png)

And my code is:

```
function generateLandingPagesReport() {
      var dataSpreadsheetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_hbaovbndsRXiwAzLk6zCmFJzc41v_qberzlaS185K8/edit"; //make sure this includes the '/edit at the end
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(dataSpreadsheetUrl);
      var deck = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
      var values = sheet.getRange('A2:l3').getValues();
      var slides = deck.getSlides();
      var templateSlide = slides[2];
      var presLength = slides.length;
      
      values.forEach(function(page){
      if(page[0]){
        
       var productImage = page[0];
       var productName = page[1];
       var productPrice = page[2];

      var productImage2 = page[3];
       var productName2 = page[4];
       var productPrice2 = page[5];
       
          var productImage3 = page[6];
       var productName3 = page[7];
       var productPrice3 = page[8];

             var productImage4 = page[9];
       var productName4 = page[10];
       var productPrice4 = page[11];
       

       templateSlide.duplicate(); //duplicate the template page
       slides = deck.getSlides(); //update the slides array for indexes and length
       newSlide = slides[2]; // declare the new page to update
        
        
        var position = {left: 0, top: 100};
    var size = {width: 150, height: 150};

        var position2 = {left: 300, top: 100};
    var size2 = {width: 150, height: 150};

        var position3 = {left: 550, top: 100};
    var size3 = {width: 150, height: 150};


       var shapes = (newSlide.getShapes());
         shapes.forEach(function(shape){
           //a.insertImage(productImage);
           shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{productName}}',productName);
           shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{productPrice}}',productPrice);

           //a.insertImage(productImage);
           shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{productName2}}',productName2);
           shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{productPrice2}}',productPrice2);

           //a.insertImage(productImage);
           shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{productName3}}',productName3);
           shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{productPrice3}}',productPrice3);

           shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{productName4}}',productName4);
           shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{productPrice4}}',productPrice4);


        }); 


               newSlide.insertImage(productImage, position.left, position.top, size.width, size.height);

               newSlide.insertImage(productImage2, position2.left, position2.top, size2.width, size2.height);

               newSlide.insertImage(productImage3, position3.left, position3.top, size3.width, size3.height);
               newSlide.insertImage(productImage4, position3.left, position3.top, size3.width, size3.height);

       presLength = slides.length; 
       newSlide.move(presLength); 
      } // end our conditional statement
      }); //close our loop of values

    //Remove the template slide
    templateSlide.remove();
      
    }
```

Now my problem is, whenever in the code to input range of data, if I put in A2:L3 , i.e. 2 rows, I get correct output in the Slide, which is 2 slides with correct data.

But if I keep the range as 3 slides, A2:L4, my slides output is wrong, it would repeat the values of the first row in 2 slides.

Can anyone give me a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template slide is slides[2].  When you duplicate the new slide is slides[3].

Change

```
newSlide = slides[2]; // declare the new page to update
```

To

```
newSlide = slides[3]; // declare the new page to update
```

Otherwise you are modifying your template for the next pass.  On the next pass the template slides[2] becomes new slide slides[3] and slides[3] becomes slides[4].

But don't forget templateSlide is always the same slide.

```
var templateSlide = slides[2];
```

Comment: I have a followup question, currently Im doing the replacealltext in a shape, but if I try the same with placeholders in a table in the slide, then the text doesnt replace.. any idea why ?

Comment: I'm assuming you are looking in every `TableCell`?  It would be best to post a new question with the script you are using to do this.

Comment: Noted, will post a new question, Thanks!